# VB.Net WinForms with Datagridview. Update not working for multiple underlying tables

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net Winform with Datagridview and bound textboxes to edit the rows. The columns are populated from Access with an SQL SELECT Command using fields from two tables. Everything works fine but I can't figure out how to save an edited row to the the underlying tables. I get an error saying "Dynamic SQL is not supported against multiple base tables". Here is my current code.  Do I have to create an Update Command for each table?

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    btnSave.Click
        JobSitesManager.EndCurrentEdit()
    Try
        'save changes to database
        Dim JobSitesAdapterCommands As New 
        OleDbCommandBuilder(JobSitesAdapter)
        JobSitesAdapter.Update(JobSitesTable)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error saving database to file:" + ControlChars.CrLf 
        + ex.Message, "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your JobSitesAdapter  SelectCommand CommandText? That will give us a clue as to what you are trying to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly haven't bothered reading about command builders. They can only be used in specific circumstances, i.e. where the query involves a single table and includes primary key information. You state specifically that you are using multiple tables so that means no command builder. You need to create `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` yourself as required.

If you want to update multiple tables then you need multiple `UPDATE` statements, which Access doesn't support in a single command. That means that you need multiple data adapters to update your multiple tables. In that case, be sure to set the `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` property of the first one to `False`. If you don't, there will be no changes left for the second one to save.